# Ensure two divs in the same wrapper are equal height

Tags: html, css

it is possible that the left (navi) div always get 100% percent of right (content) div?

if i change the height from the `.wrapper` class the `.navi` div follow them, but i need it in percent.

I can only the solution with `display: table-cell;` and `display: table-row;`

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/93a3dock/

Comment: i mean i know only the solution with display: table........ sorry for my bad english!

Comment: whats is wrong with the `display: table-cell;` and `display: table-row;` solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be accomplished by using a feature called [flex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex) (browser support [here](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox))

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 300px;
  display: flex;
}
.navi {
  background: green;
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
}
.content {
  background: yellow;
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="navi">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <!-- DYNAMIC CONTENT e.g. JOOMLA BLOG -->
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata
    sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.
    Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you that's a greate (new) solution for me! nice.

Comment: @kaito Glad to help! Remember to mark this answer as 'accepted' (click the checkmark) if you believe this is the best solution.

Comment: of course ... i am waiting a few hours more.. maybe some other guys have another good solution.

but still yours is very easy and browser support seems very good (opera mini is not a reason :D)